# Wind forecast over land accessible through python API

Tags: data-request, api, weather, python

I would like to automatically fetch wind speed forecast data over my town with a python script.

I am looking for an available dataset and API to do so.

It is for a small personal project, so it is not demanding in terms of resolution and accuracy.

So far I have tried the following:

- Windy has an API, but it seems to be javascript only.
  https://api.windy.com/
- I have tried the Copernicus Atmosphere Monitoring Service, but I only found wind speed reanalysis products, and no forecast.
  https://ads.atmosphere.copernicus.eu/#!/search?text=&type=dataset
- I have tried the Copernicus Climate Data Store, which seems to propose wind speed forecast datasets. But I couldn't download the data through their API, I am getting a "Resource not found" error, I have posted a comment on this Github issue:
  https://github.com/ecmwf/cdsapi/issues/7
- I have tried the European Centre for Medium-Range Weather Forecasts, but there doesn't seem to be wind speed forecast in their public datasets.
  https://apps.ecmwf.int/datasets/

Any idea where to look?

EDIT: 
The Windy point forecast API is accessible through HTTP requests via python, but it's not free of charge. I will investigate the models that they use (listed here: https://api.windy.com/point-forecast/docs)

Answer (score 0):

The issue for the CDS API is still open.

Initially, I was looking for a wind speed forecast dataset, accessible for download via an already existing python API. I ended up using [GFS data](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access/model-data/model-datasets/global-forcast-system-gfs). Downloading was made easy with the [Grib filter](https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/txt_descriptions/grib_filter_doc.shtml). I wrote [a small wrapper function](https://github.com/Bielorusse/duventchezmoi/blob/master/modules/download_gfs.py) in python for my project.